# SQL Server error '80040e14' with syntax error nearby "ORDER"

Tags: sql, asp-classic, syntax-error, code-injection

I have been getting the SQL Server error '80040e14' saying  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. However, the line it is pointing is the next line to the line where there is the word "ORDER" Can someone point out the syntax mistake I did in the following sql code? ASP is the language I have been using for this project.

```
SQL = " SELECT TS.ID, types"&_
      " FROM tblTickets TS"&_
      " WHERE TS.ID = "& Request("ticketid") &" ORDER BY dateof DESC"
```

SET RSticket = objConn.Execute(SQL)

So,it points error in the last line whereas "ORDER" is in different line.

Comment: Hello [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! Even with classic asp, you can use [*parameters*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675869(v=vs.85).aspx) rather than string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If Request("ticketid") returns a string value then you need to add single quotes around it:

```
SQL = " SELECT TS.ID, types"&_
      " FROM tblTickets TS"&_
      " WHERE TS.ID = '"& Request("ticketid") &"' ORDER BY dateof DESC"
```

Comment: Still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

the ORDER BY will fail, because dateof isnt a selected field

try `" WHERE TS.ID = "& Replace(Request("ticketid"),"'","''") &" ORDER BY 1 DESC"`

Comment: (added single quote escaping)

Comment: I think my suggestion is right, but I am probably being an enabler.  Damien_The_Unbeliever is right, using parameters is better, not only is it much safer from SQL Injection, but it actually can make repeat queries faster because the execute plan is the same.

Comment: You *can* order by a field that isn't selected. The only time you can't is if there's a SELECT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, ya I was just missing single quote wrap for & Request("ticketid").Now it works fine.

Comment: You need to mark TheShaman's answer as correct, if this is the case.